# Why does pink colour reduce aggressiveness?

Tags: human-biology, endocrinology, ethology

According to [this Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker-Miller_Pink), a shade of pink colour known as "Baker-Miller_Pink" has been known to reduce aggressive behaviour.

Is there any biochemical reaction responsible for this?

Specifically, are any hormones responsible for this?

If yes, then which ones?

Comment: Where did you find this claim? A source would be good...

Comment: You can just see in the wikipedia

Comment: Please put your sources in here, your question might otherwise be close as "primarily opinion based" or unclear.

Comment: The page on Wikipedia says - research has shown conflicting results....,  also see this ( http://www.orthomolecular.org/library/jom/1988/pdf/1988-v03n04-p202.pdf )

Comment: Thanks I read about that.But my question is different.

Comment: Some research have been done recently by a set of scientists different from what JM97 mentioned and their results too contradicted what was believed to be the effect of this shade of pink from the earlier experiments performed in 1970-1980. The [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Oliver_Genschow/publication/279745276_Does_Baker-Miller_pink_reduce_aggression_in_prison_detention_cells_A_critical_empirical_examination/links/55f4281f08ae6a34f660893b.pdf.).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as the quoted hypothesis is not valid according to **recent** published papers.

Comment: I think this question should remain open - a good answer should probably contain proposed hypotheses for the effect and any data towards a mechanism and/or a refutation of the existence of the phenomenon. I don't think a question should be closed based only on a faulty premise.